# How to decode query parameters in starcounter

Tags: starcounter

I have a search form. Search key is a url get parameter, the url looks like this:
http://localhost:8080/launcher/search?query=SearchStringGoesHere

Special characters are encoded in url, so when a user inputs + into the search field, url looks like this:
http://localhost:8080/launcher/search?query=%2b

On the server side query variable has value "%25252b", the question is how to get user's original value, which is "+".

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions is to use [System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(searchString)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy(v=vs.110).aspx). For example, "%2b%2b" would be converted to "++" string.